# Passing values from bash to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement bash with python can anybody help me or teach me on what should be done.
my code is

```
import io

val=os.system("echo 'sdfsfs'") #for example

print(val)
```

Comment: You mean you're trying to write a shell, or that you're trying to run bash commands via Python and capture results? It's very unclear what you're actually trying to do/achieve here... could you clarify?

Comment: I just want to test if python can accept bash results.A simple sample will do.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `os.system` is an exit code of some kind (the exact details are platform-dependent), not the text the command it ran wrote to its to standard output stream.

To get that text, you need to use a different Python command to run the program. There are a few different options, and which is best depends on more details than you've given. I'd start with [the `subprocess` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), and pick the function that works best for what you need. The [`check_output` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) seems like a good first candidate.